# Как привести массив к заданному виду

Tags: javascript

Есть массив

```
const docs = [
    {type: 'ps', number: '123456'},
    {type: 'psp', number: '223456'},
    {type: 'psp', number: '423456'},
    {type: 'vul', number: '823456'},
];
```

Как его привести к виду

```
{
    ps: [
        {number: '123456'}
    ],
    psp: [
        {number: '223456'},
        {number: '423456'},
    ],
    vul: [
        number: '823456'
    ]
}
```

Comment: на сколько я знаю `const docs` изменить нельзя т.к. `const`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант с `reduce`:

```js
const docs = [
    {type: 'ps', number: '123456'},
    {type: 'psp', number: '223456'},
    {type: 'psp', number: '423456'},
    {type: 'vul', number: '823456'},
];

let newdocs = docs.reduce((prev, item) => {
  let type = item.type;
  prev[type] = prev[type] || [];
  prev[type].push({number : item.number})
  return prev;
}, {});
console.log(newdocs);
```

Answer (score 1):

Реализация с использованием _.reduce && es6 reduce

> Ссылка на codepen: https://codepen.io/Zentro/pen/PmVJww?editors=0011

При использовании не забывайте про:
 1. accumulator - 1-й аргумент iteratee-функции | *function (**result**, item)*
 2. default accumulator , который идет 3 аргументом и в данном случае является объектом | **{}**

> *Зачем может понадобиться lodash*? Lodash позволит применить reduce не только на массив но так же и на объект **{}**.

```
    const docs = [
        {type: 'ps', number: '123456'},
        {type: 'psp', number: '223456'},
        {type: 'psp', number: '423456'},
        {type: 'vul', number: '823456'}, 
    ];

    // lodash reduce
    var reducedDocs = _.reduce(docs, function (result, item) {
        (result[item.type] || (result[item.type] = [])).push({'number': item.number});
        return result;
    }, {});

    console.log('reducedUsers', reducedDocs)


    // es6 reduce
    var es6reduce = docs.reduce((result, item) =>{
      (result[item.type] || (result[item.type] = [])).push({ 'number': item.number });
      return result
    }, {});

    console.log('es6reduce', es6reduce);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const docs = [
    {type: 'ps', number: '123456'},
    {type: 'psp', number: '223456'},
    {type: 'psp', number: '423456'},
    {type: 'vul', number: '823456'},
];

var newObj = {}; // создаем пустой объект

for (key in docs) { // пробегаемся по массиву
  if (!newObj[docs[key].type]) { // если еще нету поля
    newObj[docs[key].type] = []; // создаем его и иницализируем пустой массив
  }
  
  newObj[docs[key].type].push({number: docs[key].number}); // заполняем поле number'ом
}

console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: Немного опередили

Answer (score 0):

```
const docs = [
        {type: 'ps', number: '123456'},
        {type: 'psp', number: '223456'},
        {type: 'psp', number: '423456'},
        {type: 'vul', number: '823456'},
    ];

    var newdocs = [], i;
    for(i=0; i<docs.length; i++) {
        if(!(docs[i].type in newdocs)) {
            newdocs[docs[i].type] = [{number: docs[i].number}];
        } else {
            newdocs[docs[i].type].push({number: docs[i].number});
        }
    }
    console.log(newdocs.psp[1].number); // 423456
```